# Prevent overlay of semi-transparent background on text elements

Tags: html, css, text, background

So, there is a paragraph `<p>` with an inline element `<span>` that has a semi-transparent background `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`. It contains more than one line of text. To remove the gap between backgrounds on each line, `padding-top, padding-bottom` is used.

For example, using Open Sans 16px with 26px line-height and 2px padding -top -bottom, it renders good in Webkit desktop browsers (without gaps or overlays) but has overlays in mobile browsers (Chrome).

It could be done by applying `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` to a block element (`<p>`), but in that case the background will fill all the block, and I need it to be partially applied to some text inside a block. Not using padding is also not an option — gaps between lines with background look bad.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b3e3 0%, #2c5697 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
p {
  padding: 50px;
}
span {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</span> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</span> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</span> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Playing with padding gives different results in different browsers.

Comment: Not using a non-transparent background is also not an option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I know you said non-transparent background is not an option, I'd still argue the simplest solution is actually to go with a solid color background that is visually identical to your non-transparent tint.

For instance, `rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)` renders as `rgb(127, 127, 127)`, which makes sense, because 50% transparent black equals to 50% gray visually.

Even if you're using a colored background, say, `rgba(25, 150, 90, .5)`, it can easily be converted into a solid color—in this case, `rgb(139, 203, 173)`.

See the image for reference.

Fiddling with pixel dimension discrepancies between browser rendering engines can suck up your hours.

Comment: I have a gradient background, moreover, it changes dynamically when the accordion elements are opened. So, basically, if you open 10 of them, the initial color in the middle will change dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*The bellow seems to be buggy on Fiferox but works fine on chrome*</sup>

One idea is to use multiple background where the second one will be the same as the main container but you have to consider `background-attachment:fixed` to make both of them at the same position to create the illusion of the same one.

*I am using different colors than your exmpale to better see the result*

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue) fixed;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
p {
  padding: 50px;
}
span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,0.3),rgba(0,255,0,0.3)),
    linear-gradient(to right, red, blue) fixed;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit</span> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It actually works great in Safari, but in Chrome when you change the size of the window, it breaks. In Opera, too. Probably, in Firefox also. Updated the initial post. Any other ideas? )

Comment: @Michael on my side it works fine on Chrome but will think about another solution. By the way, don't edit your question to include my answer. Keep the original post, your comment is already enough to hightlight the issue

Comment: @Temani Afif. Ok, I will delete. Try a few paragraphs in Chrome and change the size of the window.

Comment: @Michael it breaks on the scroll to be more precise, not on resize. When you scroll the background of the span doesn't follow the other one

Comment: @Temani Afif, on scroll and also when you resize, the colors of gradient on spans change.